# Linux mount script runs in PHP interpreter but not in web Apache

Tags: php, linux, mount, overlayfs

My website is about copying files. Instead of copy the files to avoid to much time and server lagging, I decided to use overlayfs. The code `mount` the folder to the location specified in the terminal using the PHP interpreter. But, when I run the php script from Apache the script does not `mount` the overlay. And the worst is that there is no error output so I can debug what's wrong. I checked the php error log, no output about what happened.

The destination i'm mounting the overlayfs is to another user. For that I need root to execute the `mount` command. To be able to run the code without using root nor sudo, I took a look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/why-does-setuid-not-work). I created the c code, compile it and set the proper permissions (`root.root, rwsr,sr...`). I ran the code in a php file:

```
<?php
// filename over.php

print shell_exec("whoami")."\n";

print shell_exec('/var/www/vhosts/user/deployment/exec "sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var/www/vhosts/user/deployment/template5_dev,upperdir=/var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs,workdir=/var/www/vhosts/user/deployment/overlay-work /var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs"');
```

What the code does is print the actual user name (to make sure I have an output, to see if the code executed) then merge the folders. The file `/var/www/vhosts/user/deployment/exec` is the c program then I pass the code to execute as argument.

In the terminal I run: `php -f "/var/www/vhosts/user/httpdocs/over.php"`. I check the merged folder I can see it works. And the output is `user`.

Then I unmount the overlay `sudo umount /var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs`.

I access the php script via the browser, I got the output `user` but the folder does not merge. I ctrl-f5 multiple times but nothing, no error, no error in log nothing.

I changed the command to `shell_exec('/var/www/vhosts/user/deployment/exec "sudo mkdir /var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs/nouvo"');`, the `sudo` created the folder from the browser.

**I noticed that only the `mount` command does not run properly.**

What could be the reason the `sudo mount` command does not run by apache, and even if there was an error, doesn't it print out the error?

I just take a look at `/var/log/kern.log`. I can see the `mount` command got executed from the web-browser. But the log is different from the one the ones executed in the terminal.

From the web-browser:

```
 kernel: [  149.465459] overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs' not supported as upperdir
 kernel: [  151.629192] overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs' not supported as upperdir
 kernel: [  153.453612] overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/www/vhosts/user.deve/httpdocs' not supported as upperdir
```

From the terminal after executing from the browser:

```
kernel: [  312.858797] overlayfs: upperdir is in-use as upperdir/workdir of another mount, accessing files from both mounts will result in undefined behavior.
 kernel: [  312.858804] overlayfs: workdir is in-use as upperdir/workdir of another mount, accessing files from both mounts will result in undefined behavior.
```

I just don't get the log from the browser since the script is same.

Comment: Did you check Apache settings for PrivateTmp=true ?

Comment: @FatihŞennik I just checked into `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service` and `PrivateTmp=true` is uncommented.

Comment: I even commented it `#PrivateTmp=true` then reboot without success.